# reloading tableview after a segue

Tags: cocoa, viewcontroller

I have a series of table views that 'drill down' to a final view controller.  After the user has filled in a few text fields, it pushes to another one which is a congratulatory screen!  Amazing I know.  I've put a 'home' button in which (as it is a storyboard) then pushes to the first screen.  Unfortunately the table is now not populated.
 Do I have to implement some code such as [reload data] in the prepareForSegue method or is there a better/correct way to do it?
 Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you have an array that provides values for the table and this array gets updated somewhere.  Without much else to go on, I'd look at keeping a BOOL value that records whether that array has been changed.  Then, in viewDidAppear, call [table reloadData] and reset the flag if there have been changes.

Comment: Actually the array comes from a plist which isn't being changed, I don't know if that makes a difference :)  So I should still just call that method in the viewDidAppear?

Comment: It sounds as if you have something going on that's different from what I thought you were asking.  When you say 'pushes to the first screen', what's actually happening in the code?

Comment: As it is in storyboards, I created a button, ctrl and drag to first view and selected 'push' from the options (modal, custom etc.).  Sorry if I've used the wrong terminology there, I got a bit carried away with jargon :)

Comment: I've never tried that, so take this for what it's worth.... :) Assuming that your drill downs are all pushes, how about getting rid of the segue back to the start and having the button invoke an action that calls `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` on your navigation controller?  (I'm speculating that your segue creates a brand new first controller on top of everything else.)